Streamlining Video Editing: Using Grease Pencil Directly on VSE Footage
Is it possible to use Grease Pencil directly on top of footage edited in the Video Sequence Editor (VSE)? Currently, my workflow involves editing the video in VSE, rendering it as a final MP4, and then re-importing it using Add > Image > Mesh Plane. I use Grease Pencil on top of this footage and render the MP4 again. However, this process results in a second rendering step, which reduces the overall video quality.
I’m wondering if it’s possible to combine video editing in the VSE with Grease Pencil annotations in a single workflow, allowing me to render the final MP4 directly in one step, without any loss of quality. Or is there a better workflow I didn't realize exists?

I have seen this thread but take note the answer provided does not cater for a VSE that has several edits and several other clips in it. I need something that completely displays the entire VSE video output in the 2D view as reference to draw on.
Would be cool if there was something like Camera > Data Properties > Background Images > Add Active VSE and then you could see a reference video of the VSE through the camera to draw on.


as far as quality goes, you don't have to render your grease pencil with an already compressed video. you could have the video disabled in render (or use image empties instead of mesh planes, which aren't renderable), and append your grease pencil scene to the VSE where you have your original video editing.

@Lauloque true I could do that. But still I'm looking for a way to put grease pencil on VSE. Or somewhat have the currently-edited-VSE show up as the reference in 3D view. It seems what I'm asking for in the original question is not doable as single workflow? Since I still have to render out the final edited VSE video (for the reference video) and then import it as reference in 2D animation. And then render out the GP without video and then import it on top of the currently-edited-VSE video and render the final video with GP on top. But now it's 3 render steps. Even worse?

@Lauloque I suggested a new feature on right click select https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/YVyM/ what do you think?

You can use this add-on to get the VSE output as background in the camera in the 3D View:
https://github.com/tin2tin/vse_to_camera_background

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

wow exactly what I was looking for thank you so much for sharing!! just a side note, would be also cool if it worked in 2D animation workspace. Currently the VSE only shows up in the 3D View but not in the 2D animation's 3D view.

What would then be the workflow to render this footage with the GP stuff? Maybe would be cool to detail that in the answer on the usage of the addon and then how to render the footage with GP workflow?

I'm sorry. I do not have any more time to invest in trying to do a workaround for this unexisting Blender feature. If anyone wants to build on this script-solution, they're welcome.

hey don't worry thank you so much for sharing! i will just duplicate the VSE scene and then slap the GP scene on top of that to avoid recursion :)
